# How to quickly get GPS location update without googles fusedLocationClient

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Can we use the GPS antenna in way that we can control the polling speed? like every 10 seconds and every 1 second. Assume the power usage is manageable. I just want to get accurate location asap.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Android default LocationManager class which is not google API.

And also Huawei Mapkit LocationManager

val locationManager = HuaweiLocationManager(this) locationManager.registerLocationUpdates(onSuccess = { viewModel.updateCurrentLocation(it) })

and subscribe to update in different speed.

```
fun registerLocationUpdates(
        interval: Long = 10000,
        onSuccess: ((location: Location?) -> Unit)? = null,
        onFail: ((locationAvailability: LocationAvailability?) -> Unit)? = null
    ) {
        val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        // Set the location update interval (in milliseconds).
        mLocationRequest.interval = interval
        // Set the weight.
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        // Create location callback
        if (mLocationCallback == null)
            mLocationCallback = createLocationCallback(onSuccess, onFail)

        // Request location update
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest,
            mLocationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                // Requesting location updates is started successfully.
                LogUtils.d("LocationKit -> Start Location Updates Successfully")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                // Failed to start location updates.
                LogUtils.d("LocationKit -> Start Location Updates Failed with exception: ${exception.localizedMessage}")
            }
    }
```